# How to move an object in four different direction by pressing on screen in android

Tags: android

This is for learning purpose. I have a small block  that should respond to touch. IF i touch top of the screen it should move forward and right if i touch the right side of the screen.Could someone help me with the code and also what topic should i read to learn about this.

Comment: See topics ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView. You requires both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What part are you having trouble with, detecting where someone touched, drawing an object or moving an object?

Regardless I would start with some Android tutorials that walk you through creating an app with an object on it, once you have done that the rest should become obvious--it's just getting started that's hard.

Detect touch: [How do I detect touch input on the Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142670/how-do-i-detect-touch-input-on-the-android)
Moving Ojbects: http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/

Comment: detecting where someone touched, drawing an object and moving an object. I know nothing of these...

Comment: I put some examples of how to do the things you are asking.