# Cannot gain focus on edittext programmatically in Android (even after trying previous answers on Stack Overflow)

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, focus

Note: MY question is not about losing focus, it's about *gaining* focus, hence it is not a duplicate of the marked question

I have a search menuItem on my toolbar which, on click will open up a search layout ontop of it and allow user to search. I have tried the following solutions mentioned elsewhere in *Stack Overflow* but none of them seems to work. (I should mention that due to it being used elsewhere I can't edit the XML)

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991522/how-can-i-set-the-focus-and-display-the-keyboard-on-my-edittext-programmatical?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
    searchText.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(_searchText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

1. This just pops up the keyboard, nothing happens I have tried this + `editText.setCursorVisible(true);`
2. With various combinations of `setFocusable(true)` and `setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` before the aformentioned

   ```
    searchText.setFocusable(true);
    searchText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    searchText.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(_searchText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
   ```
3. Doing (1) in separate thread (using `Handler.post`)

   ```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
       handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               editText.requestFocus();
               InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
           }
       },100);
   ```
4. Calling `editText.performClick()`
5. Clearing previous focus like so:

   ```
   private void clearFocus() {
   if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getApplication().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
       activity.getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();
   }
   }
   ```

My code sample:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
        onClickForSearchMenuItem();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}

 private void onClickForSearchMenuItem() {
    if (searchLayoutInToolbar != null) {
        searchLayoutInToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) searchLayoutInToolbar.findViewById(R.id.custom_Search_Layout_Search_EditText);
        //clearFocus();
        //editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        //editText.setFocusable(true);
        editText.requestFocus();

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

The developer pages at android point out that

> A View will not take focus if one of its parents has getDescendantFocusability() equal to FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS

but none of the parents of my view are set to that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force EditText to lose focus when: some keyboard keys are pressed and when user clicks on something else in the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325325/force-edittext-to-lose-focus-when-some-keyboard-keys-are-pressed-and-when-user)

Comment: I read that, but it's about losing focus, not gaining it. Even if he explains how he got focus in the first place, he does it in xml, and not programatically.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991563/8089770

Comment: As I said in my question, I have already tried that.  and my keyboard does pop up, but the edittext is not focused

Answer (score 2):

Try This.... I hope, this may help you.

```
searchText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
searchText.requestFocus();
```

this might be required on some phones (some of the older devices):

```
final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

If not worked, try `field.requestFocus()` in the `onResume()` method of the activity (instead of the `onCreate()`).

Thanks.

Comment: As I said in my question, I have already tried the above. also, I am requesting focus only when user clicks on the search menuItem, as the edittext is not visible until that point

Comment: so, when user clicks on the search MenuItem, try calling the code, I have said in my answers. Thanks

Comment: I did do that before asking the question and it did not work!

Comment: It should work....... but as it is not working, I think, If possible , you should paste the codes in the class. Thanks