# Is there a way to change touch screen input location on Android devices for a stylus pen?

Tags: android, drawing, touch-event, stylus, pen

I have an Android tablet using Android 11.0 that I want to draw with. I purchased a stylus that is compatible with Android. The pen works on the tablet.

However, trying to draw with the tablet does not feel natural.

The actual output is shifted to the right, instead of directly underneath the stylus pen.

Is there a way to customize how your Android touch screen device responds to touch input? Does an app like this already exist? Is this even possible? I have tried calibration apps in the Play Store and they have done nothing to solve my issue. I basically want a way to "remap" the coordinates of touch input so it is shifted to the left, therefore being directly underneath my pen.

Example photo

Pictured below, the red line is a straight line created with a ruler.

The yellow line is me attempting to draw as directly down the center of the red line with the pen, using the black line as a guide to show you where I was attempting to draw the yellow line.

You can see how the output line (yellow) is shifted to the right, when where I actually was drawing was over the black line.

[image]

Comment: Reminder that StackOveflow is for programming questions. As written this appears to be end-user based and is unclear if problem is with device, pen or touch target expectation. See: [Why won't a fine-tip stylus work on my phones/tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/84564/3573)

Comment: Reading back, I see I didn't specify but I did intend for this to be a programming related question. I want to know how of its possible to code a way to remap how touch input works.

Comment: You can modify how you handle touch events in your app, [How do I detect touch input on the Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3142670/295004) but I'm not aware of any way to changing framework values that can effect multiple apps on non-root devices.